# cefsharp отключить webrtc c#

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Добрый день, можете помочь разобраться  с cefsharp, дело вот в чем :

Захожу через прокси на whoer.net в панели webrtc вижу свой реал ип, возникает логичный вопрос, а как его отключить ? Гуглил, пытался по разному, но никак не получается

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-bypass-list", "127.*,192.168.*,10.10.*,193.9.162.*");
              settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "socks5://189.102.64.13:65000");
          //  settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("webrtc.ip_handling_policy", "false");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("webrtc.multiple_routes_enabled", "false");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("webrtc.nonproxied_udp_enabled", "false");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("webrtc.ip_handling_policy", "disable_non_proxied_udp");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "0");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable_webrtc", "0");
  Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Может кто подскажет как ?

Comment: А вам [это обсуждение](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=13350) помогло?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov неа, там в комментариях предоставили пару вариантов, всех их я тестил (код выше), но ничего не помогло, обсуждение заканчивается тем, что надо попробовать `enable_webrtc` , я попробовал (поставил значение на 0, 1 - это включено) и чет все равно не помогло

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov можете еще чтот подсказать ?

Comment: Попробуйте поискать можно ли добавить расширения для Chrome с помощью cefsharp, которое будет прятать IP-адрес. Из той же ссылки там советуется https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webrtc-network-limiter/npeicpdbkakmehahjeeohfdhnlpdklia.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494323/vb-net-how-to-install-plugins-extensions-in-cef говорится, что нельзя :((

Comment: Кстати если что webrtc по умолчанию выключен, если вы просмотрите то обсуждение. Вам просто нужно чтобы IP-адрес скрывался, но похоже это невозможно данными средствами.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov да, я тоже это читал, но всеж думал, что оно все же включено, иначе почему ип показывает :( Печалька, а не подскажите еще какойт браузер, в котором можно менять передаваемые настройки ? тип юзер агент и тп и тд

Comment: А Selenium вам не подходит?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ща попробую, спасибо

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov не, это не совсем то, что нужно. Тут запускается сама лиса, что уже не очень удобно. Есть ли еще какие-то альтернативы ? если нету, то придется юзать селениум, только там бы щас разобраться, как выключить webrtc

Comment: Selenium поддерживает кучу браузеров (не только Firefox), но целевой браузер должен быть уже установлен. Альтернативы также можете попробовать поискать (не думаю, что их будет много достойных), удачи.